# How to trigger .click() event on a list of checkboxes within a page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Problem: My code below causes ALL checkboxes to be clicked (not just the ones that have the matching label / textContent) and the label itself is being changed to the text.Content I'm matching against in the if statement..

What I would like to do is to create a function (bookmarklet) that allows me to enter text for a label to match against, which will then go and find all the checkboxes with the same label and check the checkbox.

So far I'm stuck on the dom manipulation:

```
var thecollection = document.getElementById("containerELementAlwaysHasThisID").querySelectorAll("label");

for(var i=0; i < thecollection.length; i++) {
  if(thecollection[i].querySelector("span.LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName").textContent = "Menus") {
      thecollection[i].querySelector("input.inputAlwaysHasThisClassName").click();
  }
}
```

HTML structure:

```
<div id="containerELementAlwaysHasThisID">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
            <li><<label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label>/li>
            <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
      <li>
          <ul>
            <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
            <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
            <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
      <li>
          <ul>
            <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
            <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
            <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
        <li><label><input class="LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName"><span class="inputAlwaysHasThisClassName"></span></label></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `if(thecollection[i].querySelector("span.LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName").textContent = "Menus")` sets the text content to `"Menus"` and then is equivalent to `if(true)`. Did you mean to _compare_ two values here? The comparison operator is `===`. `=` is assignment.

Comment: Just an fyi: You can do `var thecollection = document.querySelectorAll("#containerELementAlwaysHasThisID label");` No need for the two look ups

Comment: Rolled back your edit which included the answer in the question post. Please read the [etiquette for answering your own question](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/289905). Answers belong only in the Answer section, whereas only questions belong in the Question section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the assignment operator in the if statement to comparison == or === fixes the script:

````
for(var i=0; i < thecollection.length; i++) {
  if(thecollection[i].querySelector("span.LabelAlwaysHasThisClassName").textContent == "Menus") {
      thecollection[i].querySelector("input.inputAlwaysHasThisClassName").click();
  }
}```
````